# Right way to Unit-test Repository.Update Method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, repository, mstest

Suppose we have typical repository

```
 public class Repository:IRepository<Entity>
    {
            public Entity GetById(int id)
            {
                //blah
            }

            public IEnumerable<Entity> All()
            {
                //blah
            }

            public void Insert(Entity entity)
            {

            }

            public void Update(Entity entity)
            {
                //blah
            }

            public void Delete(Entity entity)
            {
                //blah
            }
    }
```

Using MSTest, I want to test repository's ability to insert and update entities. As soon as it's concrete Repository, I'm testing against a real DB.

So, when I test Insert method - the strategy is clear

1. Create new entity
2. Save it
3. Fetch entity by id
4. Assert entity is returned by Repository

But when I'm thinking of Update method test it all gets somewhat tricky. 
The main questions are

- How to ensure DB has already stored objects, that I can fetch and try
  to update?
- How to test update against an empty database?

Looks like workaround would require some not necessary code and test will get bloated.
Is there any gracious solution?

Comment: You're intended 'unittest' is not really a unittest since you're not testing an isolated unit but rather an integration of multiple units. Rethink what you want to do. If you want to unit-test your code, then solely test the update method. You can do this by testing if the update method follows the intended path and leaves its instance in its intended state.

Comment: And what is the proper way to unit test my Repository class that deals with RDBMS? Somehow I need to check it does what it should.

Comment: Try and see it in this way: You want to unit test your update method. If the database fails (diskspace full for example), that doesn't mean your update method was wrong or broken. You don't need to test if your item was updated in the database. You need to check if your update method did what you expected it to do. (make the right call to the database layer for example)

Comment: A bit controversial for me. You are trying to tell that all tests against real DB are bad? Or not "Unit"? Agree that better call it "Integration-Test", but disagree that it's smth not-proper. And in your example I'd prefer to see that smth's gone wrong from such Test.

Comment: As @Polity said they are not "unit tests" but to answer your question no they are not bad, there is a difference and one does not negate the need for the other. I don't know what ORM you are using if at all but if you are injecting anything into the Repository class it is possible that you can test that the right methods are called with the right parameters when you call update on the repository. This is a unit test because you are only testing the repository, nothing else. The integration test is what you are trying to achieve and tests that you are mapping correctly to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ClassInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classinitializeattribute%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) [TestInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testinitializeattribute%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), along with [ClassCleanup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classcleanupattribute%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [TestCleanup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcleanupattribute%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to pre-populate the database with well-known entities. Then run your `Update()` tests against them.

Not sure how to interpret "not necessary code"... It looks like you are going to have to do something to populate your database in order to test the `Update()` method; at least the use of the attributes listed above allow you to implement the logic required to initialize and clean-up the database without polluting the actual test methods.

Comment: Is it possible to have different TestInitialize methods for different Test methods?

Comment: No; they're class-specific. You could separate tests into different classes though.